# python3 Execute a function when command line arg is TRUE

Tags: python-3.x, argparse

I have two functions, (1) running a demo analysis and (2) custom function that is read through a file. I would like to pass a command line argument for the user to select either the demo function or custom function as true or false. No other values needs to be passed. I am not sure what I should add within the function to accept the arg.parse

```
def demo()
    print("This is demo function")

def custom()
    print("This is custom function")


def main():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="Argument Parser is boolean to run Pipeline'")
    parser.add_argument("--demo", help='Demo data to show an example')
    parser.add_argument("--custom", help='Specify custom analysis, sql query is read from userquery.sql')
    args = parser.parse_args()

    if args.demo == True:
        demoanalysis()
    elif args.custom == True:
        customanalysis()
    else:
        print("Don't do anything")
```

However when I run the script, it goes straight to the third option.

```
python script.py --demo True --custom False
Don't do anything
```

I understand something needs to be passed to each function to accept the boolean arguments but unsure how to do it. Any suggestions. Thanks.

Comment: It's a good idea to `print(args)` before trying to use it.  That way you see just what the parser put in the Namespace.  In this case you'd see something like `Namepsace(demo='True', custom='False')`.  The values are strings, not booleans.  Your code will work if you use the right string comparison test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess, you can use `action="store_true"` argument (more in the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#action)):

```
def main():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="Argument Parser is boolean to run Pipeline'")
    parser.add_argument("--demo", action="store_true", help='Demo data to show an example')
    parser.add_argument("--custom", action="store_true", help='Specify custom analysis, sql query is read from userquery.sql')
    args = parser.parse_args()

    if args.demo:  # need no comparison with True, because demo is True or False itself
        demoanalysis()
    elif args.custom:
        customanalysis()
    else:
        print("Don't do anything")
```

**Edit**: If there's no keyword in command line argument, `store_true` creates `False` values by default.
Usage examples:

```
python demo_script.py --demo  # prints "This is demo function"
python demo_script.py --custom  # prints "This is custom function"
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: I type: python script.py --demo true --custom false. For which, I get this error - usage: script.py [-h] [--demo] [--custom]
script.py: error: unrecognized arguments: true false

Comment: I found my error. I just ran python script.py --demo and it worked. Thanks

Comment: Thanks, I've added examples for clarity if someone else will read this answer

Answer (score 0):

You can also build a function to check whether the argument you passed to the function is valid:

```
def main():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="Argument Parser is boolean to run Pipeline'")
    # Here you add a type definition to your arguments
    parser.register('type', 'bool', (lambda x: str(x).lower() == "true") )
    parser.add_argument("--demo", type="bool", help='Demo data to show an example')
    parser.add_argument("--custom", type="bool", help='Specify custom analysis, sql query is read from userquery.sql')
    args = parser.parse_args()

    if args.demo:
        demoanalysis()
    elif args.custom:
        customanalysis()
    else:
        print("Don't do anything")
```